# EAGAIN on a blocking read system call on regular file

Tags: c, linux, input, posix, errno

So, this is a weird case that I am seeing sometimes and not able to figure out a reason.

We have a C program that reads from a regular file. And there are other processes which write into the same file. The application is based on the fact that the writes are atomic in Linux for write size up to 4096 bytes.

The file is NOT opened with non blocking flag, so my assumption is that reads would be blocking.

But sometimes during the startup, we see "*Resource temporarily unavailable*" error set in `errno`. And the size returned by read != -1 but some partially read size.

An error message would look something like:

```
 2018-08-07T06:40:52.991141Z, Invalid message size, log_s.bin, fd 670, Resource temporarily unavailable, read size 285, expected size 525
```

My questions are:

1. Why are we getting `EAGAIN` on blocking file read?
2. Why is the return value not -1?
3. This happens only during the initial time when it is started. It works fine thereafter. What are some edge cases that can get us in such situation?

Comment: When it starts at that time it doesn’t have any data to read so read is waiting for the data to read,  read is blocking that’s why your getting EAGAIN.

Comment: If the write is said to be atomic, then why should it be waiting at all ? All the 525 bytes for the above error message should have been available, right ?

Comment: In which kind of file system the file you read is stored in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why are we getting EAGAIN on blocking file read ?

You aren't (see below).

> Why is the return value not -1 ?

Because the operation did not fail.

The value of `errno` **only** carries a sane value if the call to `read()` failed. A call to `read()` failed if and only if `-1` is returned.

From the [Linux man-page for `read()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end
>          of file), and the file position is advanced by this number.  It is
>          not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes
>          requested;
>
> [...]
>
> On error, -1 is returned, and `errno` is set appropriately.

A common pattern to `read()` would be

```
char buffer[BUFFER_MAX];
char * p = buffer;
size_t to_read = ... /* not larger then BUFFER_MAX! */

while (to_read > 0)
{
  ssize_t result = read(..., p, to_read);
  if (-1 == result)
  {
    if (EAGAIN == errno || EWOULDBLOCK == errno)
    {
      continue;
    }

    if (EINTR == errno)
    {
      continue; /* or break depending on application design. */
    }

    perror("read() failed");

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else if (0 < result)
  {
    to_read -= (size_t) result;
    p += (size_t) result;
  }
  else if (0 == result) /* end of file  /  connection shut down for reading */
  {
    break;
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "read() returned the unexpected value of %zd. You probably hit a (kernel) bug ... :-/\n", result);

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}

If (0 < to_read)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Encountered early end of stream. %zu bytes not read.\n", to_read);
}
```

Comment: Yes, definitely; nice!